# COUNT() with PARTITION generates inconsistent result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please consider the below T-SQL statements.

```
    SELECT 
           [isin],
           v_year,
           growth_start,
           COUNT(v_year)     OVER (PARTITION BY isin) as n_count,
           MAX(growth_start) OVER (PARTITION BY isin) as max_growth_start
      FROM valuation_basic
     WHERE isin = 'CH0012221716'
  GROUP BY isin, v_year, growth_start
  ORDER BY v_year

  SELECT count(v_year)     FROM valuation_basic WHERE isin = 'CH0012221716'
  SELECT max(growth_start) FROM valuation_basic WHERE isin = 'CH0012221716'
```

[image]

I am expecting the `n_count` column to have the same values as `SELECT count(v_year) FROM valuation_basic WHERE isin = 'CH0012221716'`. However, their values differ significantly (336 vs 245).

Why is this? I thought the statement `COUNT(v_year) OVER (PARTITION BY isin) as n_count` would give the row count by the unique identifier `isin` column.

Comment: This is actually a really good question.  I don't know why anyone would downvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression:

```
COUNT(v_year) OVER (PARTITION BY isin) as n_count,
```

Happens *after* the aggregation.  So, it is counting the number of rows in the *result set*.  That has nothing to do with the number of original rows summarized in each group.

Instead, you want the `SUM()` of the counts in each row, so you want:

```
SUM(COUNT(v_year)) OVER (PARTITION BY isin) as n_count,
```

The `COUNT()` is the aggregation function.  It is counting the original rows summarized in each group.  The `SUM() OVER` is a window function.  It is then summing the counts -- which is the overall count.

Here is a simple example:

```
x    
a 
a
a
b
```

This query:

```
select x, count(*)
from t
group by x;
```

Returns:

```
a      3
b      1
```

Note what this returns:

```
select x, count(*),
       count(*) over (),
       sum(count(*)) over (),
       max(count(*)) over ()
from t
group by x;
```

The results are:

```
a      3      2      4      3
b      1      2      4      3
```

The `2` is because there are two rows in the result set.  The `4` is because `3 + 1 = 4`.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any reference to where I can read more about this?

Comment: What I am confused about is that the MAX(growth_start)  OVER (PARTITION BY isin) as max_growth_start gives the correct result. Why is this? If I remove the partition by statement the results get all messed up again.

Comment: @uncool . . . Because it is picking a value from the rows, not counting the rows.

Comment: Thank you again (I'm very new to tsql). One last thing that I can't wrap my head around. If both partition by statements are picking values from the aggregated table. How can SUM(COUNT(v_year)) be the actual number of rows? Is the COUNT() inside the SUM() a subquery that is executed on the original non-aggregated table?